# How to access ASP controls nested within DataList Item Template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access a control that is nested within a DataList ItemTemplate. For the life of me, I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. An example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
            </div>
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSavings" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In the code behind I am trying to access the "lblSavings" label control as such:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSavings.Text = "String";
    }
}
```

It's like the code behind cannot see that control or something. Am I missing a step somewhere, or am I just crazy?

Thanks all!

Comment: is that a compiling error? I'd try to set its value in datalist's 'itemDataBound' event...

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this will help you.
Feel free to ask if got any query.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          Label lbl   = Datalist1.Item.FindControl("lblSavings") as Label;
} 

or at time of item bound

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs 
e) 
{
Label Label1 = e.Item.FindControl("lblSavings") as Label;
}
```